# Laravel Eloquent get data from two tables through an intermediate table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following three tables :

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string

tracker_sessions
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    geoip_id - integer

tracker_geoip
    id - integer
    country - string
```

These are my models :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function tracker_geoip(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\TrackerGeo', 'App\TrackerSession', 'geoip_id', 'id', 'id');
    }
    public function tracker_sessions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TrackerSession');
    }
}

class TrackerGeo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tracker_geoip';
}

class TrackerSession extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tracker_sessions';
}
```

Is it possible to get this result using Eloquent ? :

```
0 => [
     'name' => 'John Smith',
     'geoip' => ['id' => 12, 'country' => 'Greenland']
]
```

I've tried this :

```
$usersWithGeo = App\User::with('tracker_geoip')->get()->toArray();
```

This does return an array of user info , but the tracker_geoip sub array is always empty even if there are records in the tables.

Comment: Why do you need a model for *tracker_sessions*? Laravel will handle many-to-many relationship automatically for you.

Comment: @TheFallen actually he is not using a pivot table. so he needs the model

Comment: have you tried using `load()` method as well. i.e `App\User::load('tracker_geoip');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your table structure, the relationship for `tracker_geoip` should actually be a `belongsToMany` not a `hasManyThrough`.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\TrackerGeo', 'tracker_sessions', 'user_id', 'geoip_id')->distinct();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you ! Your suggestion did work , but now 'tracker_geoip' sub array has a lot of duplicated indexes . It has the same number of indexes as the user's sessions count. Any chance I could get only a single index , like this : 'tracker_geoip' => ['id' => 12, 'country' => 'Greenland']. May be filter with subquery ?

Comment: In that case you just need to add `distinct()` to your relationship. I've updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code (avoiding relationships):

```
class TrackerSession extends Model
{
    public function getGeoipNameAttribute(){
        return TrackerGeo::where('id', $this->attributes['geoip_id'])->first(); //you can stop here or add ->country; to get only the country name
    };
}
```

The above method retrieves the country name of a `TrackerGeo` collection with the given id.

Now what you need is get all the tracker sessions for the given user. So in the user model we have:

```
public function getTrackerSessionAttribute(){
    return TrackerSession::where('user_id', %this->attributes['id'])->get() //or first() depends on the number of records you want to retrieve.
}
```

and on your view you can do the following:

```
$user->tracker_session->geoip_name // ->country depends on the return result
```

if you have retrieved only 1 record with the `first()` Eloquent method, or

```
@foreach($user->tracker_session as $session)
    {{$session->geoip_name}} // {{$session->geoip_name->country}} depends on the return result
@endforeach
```

notice that you can access the collections by using the snake case name of the method as an attribute of the main model.